# Trouble understanding continuity of a function on the integers.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

so I'm having a bit of trouble understanding when I can apply continuity and the conditions for when it exists. The standard definition that I was taught is that if a function $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$. Then this implies that the limit exists and, more formally, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta $ s.t if $|x-a|<\delta$ and $x\in Dom(f)$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

This definition seemed fine for me, since its just the normal limit definition, setting L as $f(a)$. However, I was trouble when we were introduced to this function:

Take $f: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(a)=a+1$, then $f$ is continuous at $x=0 $

Clearly (intuitively), I understood that this limit does not exist. However, I could not understand how this can be continuous, as I thought that the limit had to exist.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could prove this is continuous and/or provide some more intuition to the formal definition.

Comment: $f$ is not a function on $\mathbb{R}$, so the usual notion of continuity may not apply here. What topology are you using here?

Comment: According to your definition, take $\delta = 1$ and the result follows.

Comment: Take $\delta = 1$.  Then the only value of $x$ within distance $\delta$ to zero is identically zero and so every value (*all one of them*) of $x$ within that range will have $|f(x)-f(0)|=0<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Answer (score 1):

Of course the limit exists. For any $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=1/2$ , then the statement that if $|x−a|<\delta$ and $x\in \text{Dom}(f)$, then $|f(x)−f(a)|<\epsilon$, would be true.

Function on a discrete set is always continuous.